# Please tell me how to upload the text image of Summernote

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular7, text-editor, summernote

The frontend uses angular 6 and the api uses asp.net core.
When you add an image to the body, it asks the api to save the file on the server.
By the way, when data is saved, it is saved as base64 bytes.
The database should be stored under 4000 bytes using Oracle.
Is there any way to upload an image via the image path?
I hope you can tell me how to write the uploadImagePath callback function in the angular example.

```
config: any = {
airMode: false,
tabDisable: true,
placeholder: '내용을 입력하세요.',
tabsize: 2,
height: '300px',
uploadImagePath: this.REST_API_ADDR + 'File/summernote',
popover: {
  table: [
    ['add', ['addRowDown', 'addRowUp', 'addColLeft', 'addColRight']],
    ['delete', ['deleteRow', 'deleteCol', 'deleteTable']],
  ],
  image: [
    ['image', ['resizeFull', 'resizeHalf', 'resizeQuarter', 'resizeNone']],
    ['float', ['floatLeft', 'floatRight', 'floatNone']],
    ['remove', ['removeMedia']],
  ],
  link: [['link', ['linkDialogShow', 'unlink']]],
  air: [ ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear',],],],
},
toolbar: [
  ['misc', ['codeview', 'undo', 'redo']],
  ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
  ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
  ['fontsize', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'color']],
  ['para', ['style', 'ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'height']],
  ['insert', ['table', 'picture', 'link', 'video', 'hr']],
],
fontNames: ['Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New', 'Roboto', 'Times'],
  }
```